# Model overall effect of predictor within categories

Tags: r, regression, generalized-linear-model, categorical-encoding

I'm trying to fit a generalized linear model in R, but am quite new to regression, and struggling to work out how to have predictors nested within categorical variables.

An example of my data:

```
Response   Predictor   Category  
1          1.22           A  
5          5.67           A  
3          4.52           B  
3          7.23           B  
9          2.75           C  
4          1.11           C
```

etc....

I want to test for an effect of the Predictor on the Response, within each Category.  I have been able to test within each Category by sub-setting the data into each Category, but then I get lots of different test results.  I thought there is probably a way to do an overall test, but I can't figure out what formula I'd use.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't tell us a lot about your data and which generalized linear model you want to fit, but the main question seems to be about how to model the linear predictor as a function of the covariates.  Since the response seems to be a count, I will write example code for a poisson regression  (in R, and poisson regression by default uses a log link function). So

```
out1  <-  glm(Response ~ Category + Predictor, family=poisson, data=your.data.frame)
```

where your.data.frame is a data frame containing the variables, `Response` as numerical variable, `Predictor` as numeric, while `Category` must be coded as factor.  The code above estimates a simple model with separate intercepts for A, B and C, and a common slope for `Predictor`.

To code a model with separate slopes for A,B and C we need to include an interaction, which you can do as

```
out2  <-  glm(Response ~ Category * Predictor, family=poisson, data=your.data.frame)
```

the only change to the call is that a `+` was replaced with a `*`, which in R is the crossing operator, which expands to `Category + Predictor + Category:Predictor`, adding the interactions.